# Maybe vs Probably? There is a lot of confusion

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Maybe/Might = >0% something will occur

Probably = It is likely something will occur

Why does saying "probably" imply more confidence than "maybe/might" if both imply that something will possibly occur?

Context:

Person A is hosting a party, and invited Person B, but Person B has not replied. Person A sees Person B, and asks:

Person A: "Are you coming to my party?"

1. Person B: "Maybe." This introduces a possibility that the person will come. It does not say anything about the measure of the possibility, though.
2. Person B: "Probably." This introduces a high possibility that the person will come. "Probably" also implies "might".

Why is "Maybe" thought of "less probable" than "Probably" if the measure of possibility for "maybe" is unknown? It could be "high possibiligy" as well?

Comment: It's the definition of "probable".

Answer (score 1):

So far as the semantics is concerned *maybe*, indeed, includes any probability greater than zero; it thus includes in its meaning the relatively higher probabilities, that are covered by the meaning of *probably*. However, as a matter of pragmatics, one is unlikely to use *maybe* if one knows that whatever we are talking about is probable; the use of *maybe* thus pragmatically implicates, even though it does not logically imply, that, so far as the speaker knows, the probability is relatively low. If something is, in fact, probable, then saying that it is probable is more informative, and so more helpful to one's interlocutor, than saying that maybe it will happen. People who communicate cooperatively normally don't use a broader term when a narrower, more informative one could be used without any additional effort.

If one is keen to understand such matters better, one may wish to spend some time studying the work of Paul Grice.

Comment: I don’t think “maybe” excludes “maybe not.” So I don’t think the probability is > 0.

Comment: Of course, *maybe* does not exclude *maybe not* (and is even compatible with *probably not*), but that does not mean that *maybe* could be used when the probability is zero. If the probability of something is, say, 20% (a case in which *maybe* would be perfectly apt), then the probability of its not happening is 80%. The probability being zero would, however, mean that it is certain (not merely possible) that whatever we are talking about will not happen, and in such a case one would not use *maybe*.

Answer (score 1):

On this topic, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* makes the following distinction (p769):

> *Probably* explicitly allows for the possibility that the proposition is not true, but rates the chances of its being true as greater than
> even.
>
> *Maybe*, *perhaps*, *possibly*, indicate that the proposition is not known to be false, with the chances of its being true falling in the
> range from slight to more or less fifty-fifty.

Answer (score 0):

[Probable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/probable):

> supported by evidence strong enough to establish presumption but not
> proof

Answer (score -1):

**First:**

A: “Why is that man looking at that car?

B(i): “I don’t know… **perhaps** he is a policeman.”

B(ii): “I don’t know… **maybe** he is a policeman.”

B(iii): “I don’t know… he **may be** a policeman.”

Are all, in current English, semantically identical: they all mean

B(iv): “I don’t know… **My guess is that** he is a policeman.” or "**There is some probability** that he is a policeman.

B’s guess must have a reason of some sort and **perhaps**, **maybe** and **may be** all express the same degree of confidence that B has that his guess is accurate. Thus they express the degree of **probability** that B gives to the man's being a policeman.

In earlier English, there was a distinction between “**perhaps**” and “**maybe**”, but there was no real difference between “**maybe**” and “**may be**.”

“**Perhaps**” is formed from “**per**”[1], which is preposition = *by or through the means of,* and  “hap” [2], a noun, which is archaic English for “*luck, chance, fate, or fortune.*”

Thus “**perhaps**” (adv.) – **by luck, chance, fate, or fortune**,” and we can see that **in the *older* meaning**, B(i): “I don’t know… **perhaps** he is a policeman.” Does not work, as it means B(i): “I don’t know…  *[un]luckily or [un]fortunately* he is a policeman.”

But if we say “Let’s go to John’s house - **perhaps** he is at home.” You are saying “Let’s go to John’s house, **if we are lucky**, he will be at home.”

Luck, chance, fate, or fortune are all uncertain – we cannot know if we will be lucky or fortunate. Thus by adding “**perhaps**” we add uncertainty to the statement and reduce the statement to a statement of probability.

If we say *“Let’s go to John’s house, **maybe**(adv.)[3] he is at home.”* Maybe is an adverb formed from “may(modal v.)[4]” + “be(v.)” meaning *“it is **permitted or allowed** be the case that”*. This expresses some uncertainty but is **not** dependant upon luck, chance, fate, or fortune: It is an estimation of the probability of John’s being at home based upon experience of him, and people in general, being at home.

If we say *“Let’s go to John’s house, he **may be** at home.”* **May be** is {modal verb + infinitive}. In this sense, “**may**”, expresses **the permission or allowance** of some fact, i.e. the idea that *John **is** at home* is something that we are reasonably **allowed or permitted** to accept/believe (as being logical) and this is based upon our experience of John, and people in general, being at home. It does not rely upon luck, fate or fortune.

You will see that we cannot know the state, position or condition of anything for which we have no solid data. We do not know for certain that John is or is not at home. Thus in all the above the sentences express some sort of probability.

There is yet another word “**mayhap**[5]”. This is archaic or regional or poetic, and is a shortened form of ***it may hap*** = *it pron. + may v. + hap v*[6]. where “to hap” (archaic or regional or poetic) = To have or enjoy luck (of a specified kind); to fare (well or badly). The verb *to hap* is now replaced by “**to happen**” -> “I **happened** (formerly = happed) to find a £10 note, so we were able to buy food.”

---

All from OED:

[1] **II. By.  3.c. By means of. Chiefly in phrases relating to conveyance, as per bearer, per carrier, per express, per post, per rail, per steamer, etc. Now rare (chiefly archaic).**

1894   ‘M. Twain’ Pudd'nhead Wilson i. 17   *The town of Dawson's Landing,..half a day's journey, per steamboat, below St. Louis.*

[2] **2. The chance or fortune that falls to a person; (one's) luck, lot; (also) an instance of this. Frequently modified by good (also bad, evil, etc.) and by possessive adjective.**

1917   M. Hewlett Thorgils xi. 94   *We had bad hap in driving on to this wilderness of rock and ice, and have never been able to mend our fortunes yet.*

2012   Pittsburgh Post-Gaz. (Nexis) 22 Dec. w10   *Two interlocking plays..in adjacent theaters trace the comic haps and mishaps at an English country estate.*

[3] **Etymology:** Shortened < it may be < it pron. + may v.1 + be v.

[4]  ***5. Expressing objective possibility, opportunity, or absence of prohibitive conditions; have the potentiality to, be at liberty to, **be permitted by circumstances to.*****

1902   V. Jacob Sheep-stealers viii   *‘How do you get it all up to Abergavenny?’ ‘Ah, you may well ask.’*

[5] **Etymology:** Shortened < it may hap < it pron. + may v.1 + hap v.1

[6] **Now regional and archaic. †1. intransitive. To have or enjoy luck (of a specified kind); to fare (well or badly). 2. intransitive. To come about by chance; to happen, come to pass, occur. Formerly sometimes with be (rather than have) as auxiliary. Cf. happen v.** 1.

**a. With the action expressed by a clause or infinitive typically following the verb, usually impersonal or with non-referential it as subject.**

**†(a) With indirect object expressing the person affected by an occurrence. Obsolete.**

1533   T. More Debellacyon Salem & Bizance Pref. p. iii   *How it happed me to fall in hand therwyth, and to spende and lese a lytell tyme about it, to make the mater the more playne vnto you.*

**(b) Without indirect object.** Now rare.

1995   M. Frayn in Guardian 19 Apr. a10/2   *Then murmureth the prophet unto himself... It may hap that we are entering upon a time of prosperity and sustained growth without concomitant inflation.*